# Valentina Studio inset a millions of rows

Tags: sql, insert, valentina-studio

I have txt file with insert statements with few millions of rows. 
I want to insert them inside database, but I can't copy and paste in Valentina because it is too much for SQL window.

How do I insert in batch from a file?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Every DBMS has a command line tool that can efficiently execute large SQL scripts (`psql` for Postgres, `sqlpls` for Oracle, ...)

Comment: I use Postgres database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valentina Studio has command "Load Dump...", which can load big files with any SQL commands, including inserts.

You can find this command in the menu File or in the contextual menu of a Database object in the Schema Editor.